# Writing Unicode characters from Java using Apache POI XSSF to an Excel file ".xlsx"

Tags: java, unicode, apache-poi

I am working on a project that is currently using [POI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_POI) to write out to an Excel file using the XSSF Workbook. I have an issue with writing out [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters to the Excel document and having them displaying correctly.

I am using Pattern and Matcher to find and replace other tags in text with the corresponding Unicode characters.

```
private static String replaceTags(String stringToChange, String replacementTag, String originalTag) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(originalTag);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringToChange);
    return matcher.replaceAll(replacementTag);
}
```

I call that function in my code to find and replace tags in my text. It's working for most of my replacement tags, but not for things like the Trademark symbol and the quotation mark, because I can't use the actual symbol for them as replacements, I have to put the Unicode for them.

```
if (replacementString.contains("%0022")) {
    replacementString = replaceTags(replacementString, "\\U005C", "%0022");
}
c.setCellValue(replacementString);
```

Now the problem I'm running into is when I write the string to the Excel file Excel ignores the backslash in front of the `U005C` and just writes the code out like normal text. Is there a way to get these characters to appear from the code that I'm missing or is it even possible to do?

**Update:**

I have gotten every symbol I need to work except for the quotation mark. Using `\\\\U005c` or `\\\\U0022` has the Excel spreadsheet displaying \U005c or \U0022 instead of `"`.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe you need double escaping because the Excel format is itself quoted internally... i.e. `"\\\\U005C"`

Comment: Write `"\\\\U005C"`. Did not understand the entire context though.

Comment: Here's a little more context of the program. We have two columns in this spreadsheet, one column contains blocks of text that contain tags indicating special symbols that would go in the place of those tags. Ex: Instead of the cell saying "Hello world" it would say 
%2122Hello world%2122. Using those tags to signify the quotes. The other column is going to display the full text, including the special characters like quotation marks, punctuation etc.

What you guys suggested has the program putting out and excel displaying the slash, but i need excel to display the character not the unicode.

Comment: Have you made sure that your font actually has all the required characters in it?